# Relationship queries in Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm very new to Laravel, and am having trouble understanding queries in Eloquent. I have two models - Laptop and Location. Suppose I want to query all the laptops belonging to a location that has a 'stock' value of 1. In SQL this would be a left join, but how do I do this in Eloquent? I've already added the relationships to the two models, so the Laptop model has a 'location' method, but where do I go from there?

Comment: Can you show us the table structure and your relationship code?

Comment: yes please, post also your db structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query scopes for that. They are thoroughly documented in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)

In the laptop model you can write a scope for the stockcheck:

```
public function scopeInStock($query)
{
    return $query->where('stock', 1);
}
```

To keep it clean you can then create another relation in the Location model:

```
public function laptopsInStock()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Laptop')->inStock();
   // or this way:
   // return $this->laptops()->inStock();
}
```

Now to retreive the results there are a couple of options:

```
//all laptops
$location->laptops;

// in stock only
$location->laptopsInStock;

// eager loading
$location->with('laptopsInStock')->get();
```

Comment: The 'stock' column is in the locations table, not the laptops table. That's my problem - I want all laptops from all locations where the stock value is one.

Comment: So all you would need is:
`$laptops = Laptop::inStock()->get();`

Comment: Doesn't work, I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stock' in 'where clause' `

Comment: O right, you had the stock field in the Location table. Try to put the `inStock` query scope in the Location model and do the following:
`$locations = Location::inStock()->with('laptops')->get();`

Comment: Finally, some data from my query! Thankyou. So...how would I go about injecting further query parameters the user might have entered? For example, the model, or the type of the model (so that's two tables away from each laptop...), and how do I do this without making each page load generate ten million SQL queries? This is so easy in raw SQL...

Comment: Is there a specific reason to store model and type in their own tables instead of storing that information inside the laptops table itself? 

Raw SQL can be executed if you would like to trim down your query count. It's pretty well [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Since you've not provided any code so I'm going to describe from basic.

**Migrations**

Locations Table

```
Schema::create('locations', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Laptop Table

```
Schema::create('laptops', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('stock');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('location_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('locations')
          ->onDelete('cascade')
          ->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

**Models**

Location Model

```
class Location extends Model {
    public function laptops(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Laptop');
    }
}
```

Laptop Model

```
class Laptop extends Model {
    public function location(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Location');
    }
}
```

If you've created your app like this then there are several way to achieve the goal.
This will query all the laptop belonging to a location and that has a stock value `1`.

1.

```
Laptop::where('location_id','some_location_id')->where('stock',1)->get();
```

2

```
Location::where('id','some_location_id')->with(['laptops' => function($query){
     $query->where('stock',1);
}])->get();
```

I hope this would solve your problem. Feel free to comment and ask whatever question you have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not have the foreign key in the migration - I was under the impression that the belongsTo and hasMany declarations in the models was enough? Ultimately, I want to return an initial view that grabs all laptops from stock locations, but this query will then become much more complicated, allowing the user to filter by any combination of model, type, location etc. I have a similar one-to-many relationship with Model.

Comment: And just to add, this code currently `$laptops = Laptop::where('stock', 1)->get();` produces a Column not found error. Edit: to clarify further, I do not want to limit the results to a particular location - I want results from all locations that have a stock value of 1. And / or I want results from all laptop models matching the user's selection.

Comment: `column not found` error is because of you're trying to access column which doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Also, for much more complicated design I would recommend you to keep your code tight and base stronger. There are some videos in laracast on eloquent, watch them it will help you to make your concept stronger.